# Hardware sizing

Tags: sizing

Basically I am looking for the guidelines for How to approach on hard ware sizing for a
given requirements.what are the parameters need to consider to arrive at sizing decisons.
It will be really great if any body can help on identifing sizing details for appserver,
webserver,database etc..Please

Comment: Your question is too unspecific to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well usually what you do in such cases is follow the hardware sizing sheet supplied by the product vendor for the particular appserver / database. Some of the common parameters you need will be availability window, number of concurrent users, disk space consumed, application memory requirements etc.